# React hello world doesn't work with ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with my code? I see no error in the console of jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/susumidode/edit?js,console,output

```
Class secondComponenent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <p>My id is: {this.props.id}</p>
    );
  } 
} 


React.render(
  <secondComponenent id="abc">,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

And also how to render multiple component in React.render()?

Comment: Class names must begin with a capital letter.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/KuPUr

Comment: @Whitcik that doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a couple of minor syntax errors holding you back. Lower case for class, upper case for naming the component, and closing off the component to be rendered. This code below works in your JSBin.

```
class SecondComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <p>My id is: {this.props.id}</p>
    );
  } 
} 


React.render(
  <SecondComponent id="abc" />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to use `ReactDOM` to render your component to the browser not `React`. 
You code is:

```
React.render(
    <secondComponenent id="abc" />,
    document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

But in recent versions of `React` (above 0.14) it must be:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <secondComponenent id="abc" />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

To make it work you can add this [library](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/t39.3284-6/13176340_977137305734260_1146243719_n.js) to your html.

Second, you must close your component when it hasn't child components like this: `<secondComponent id="abc" />`, your writing like this: `<secondComponent id="abc">`.

In order to render multiple components in react, you have to wrap them with a single parent component for example like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <firstComponenent id="abc" />
        <secondComponenent id="abc" />
    </div>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

**P.S**: Also, as @alexi2 says: `class SomeComponent` not `Class SomeComponent`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is not needed if `react` version is below `0.14`. But with recent versions you must use `ReactDOM` anyway. Maybe helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007402/is-there-any-difference-between-react-render-and-reactdom-render.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use props, you (may) need a constructor (please see the comments below this answer).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class SecoundComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.props = props;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p>My id is: {this.props.id}</p>
    )
  }
}

render(<SecoundComponent id="123" />, document.getElementById('react_example'));
```

Also note that I named the class `SecoundComponent`, with capital S.

Comment: This isn't true. You need to use a constructor to use `this.state`, but props are applied automatically.

Comment: You're right, @JoshuaComeau, but if you'd want to use props inside the constructor, then you'd need to use `super(props)`. See http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/XjNWqq?editors=0010

Comment: True - If you define your own constructor, you need to ensure that `Component`'s original constructor still receives the props. Otherwise, your constructor will overwrite the original one, and `this.props` will never be set.

Comment: this is way complicated, why above alex2's answer worked without importing anything?

Comment: You're propably just getting React and ReactDOM from external libraries ;-) This here is more "es6-y" approach.