# Hello world doesn't work in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**[Updates:]**

1. So you need Babel https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js
2. React has changed it's API and ReactDom should be used -> [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007402/is-there-any-difference-between-react-render-and-reactdom-render).

---

So I tried to give react a shot and either I'm too far down a rabbit hole but I can't seem to figure while the extremely simple page just doesn't load up and work..

I have just react_hello.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="root">
<body>
    <script type="text/babel">
    console.log("A");
        var ExampleElement = React.createClass({
            render : function() 
            { 
                return (<p>Testing 123</p>);
            };
        });
        React.render(<ExampleElement/>, document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work both in Chrome and Firefox, I see a blank page and get this in the console:

> Download the React DevTools and use an HTTP server (instead of a file: URL) for a better development experience: https://fb_dot_me_url_blocked/react-devtools

Sure I could download the dev tools but I don't want to because I want to understand grounds up how it works. Why don't I see tutorials that point to the basic idea of how to setup a page with react!! Even https://facebook.github.io/react/ uses codepen.

Comment: Try adding babel script as well,   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"> </script>

Comment: @LucasOliveira this seems to be more the right answer, a more fundamental requirement that one needs babel. Along with ReactDom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you define this `<div id="root"` outside of the `body`.
Try this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title of the document</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="root"/>
      <script type="text/babel">
         console.log("A");
         var ExampleElement = React.createClass({
            render : function() 
            { 
                return (<p>Testing 123</p>);
            };
         });
         ReactDOM.render(<ExampleElement/>, document.getElementById('root'));
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Another change is, you need to use `ReactDOM.render` instead of `React.render`, check the difference between this two: [Is there any difference between React.render() and ReactDOM.render()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007402/is-there-any-difference-between-react-render-and-reactdom-render)

Comment: Yes, I corrected this..

Comment: read this, ur ques is answered here  very well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007402/is-there-any-difference-between-react-render-and-reactdom-render

Answer (score 1):

```
ReactDOM.render(<ExampleElement/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Why does this work and not React and why do so many examples seem to do React instead of ReactDOM?